# How can i make for loop reading information from json object in java?

Tags: java, selenium, maven, for-loop

I have the following JSON array below, I want to make a for loop that extracting each username, pass, err from each object inside the array. how this can be done in java.

```
[
  {
    "username": "",
    "password": "",
    "expectedError": "Enter your user ID."
  },
  {
    "username": "exa",
    "password": "",
    "expectedError": "Enter your password."
  }
]
```

here is the method I have used for reading the json file

```
public static JSONArray parseJsonFile () {
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    try (FileReader reader = new FileReader("src/main/resources/list.json")){
        Object obj = jsonParser.parse(reader);
        JSONArray list = (JSONArray) obj;
        System.out.println(list);
        return list;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

here is where I want the extracted the data be used

```
public void loginWith(String username, String password) {
    usernameInput.clear();
    usernameInput.sendKeys(username); // want to extract the value of username in json file and send it herejaza
    passwordInput.clear();
    passwordInput.sendKeys(password);
    signInButton.click();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy with jacksonAPI. Look below and see the tutorial from Baeldung site:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
...
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

   List<User> listUsers = objectMapper.readValue(stringFromFile, new TypeReference<List<User>>(){});


...
```

[Tutorial Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial)